# Show that natural exponential function is well-defined

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, logarithms, exponential-function, real-numbers

Thomas' Calculus p. 440 (Early Transcendental version, 14th edition), author defines the natural exponential function this way:

> For every *real* number $x$, we define the natural exponential function to be $e^{x} = \exp(x)$.

Where $\exp$ denotes the inverse function of $\ln$, and $e$ is a number such that $\ln(e) = 1$.

The natural logarithm is defined to be:

$$
\ln x=\int_1^x \frac{1}{t}dt, x>0.
$$

The author gives a very readable proof of the validity of the definition of natural exponential function (the equality $e^{x} = \exp(x)$ to be specific), but only for all x that are *rational*. So, is there any proof of the validity for irrational x also?

The reason I believe the proof for the irrational part is necessary is because several important results are deduced based on the equality. Only accept that it's true and move on is fine, but it's not satisfactory.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm interpreting this correctly, you are asking how to prove the definition $\ln x = \int_1^{x} \frac{1}{t}dt$ when $x$ is an irrational number? "Proving" a definition makes no sense.

Comment: @Accelerator, I mean the equality $e^{x} = exp(x)$, the definition of natural logarithm is taken for granted.

Comment: Apostol is *not* taking the definition of natural log for granted. He is instead defining it to be the definite integral you mention.

Comment: The equality $e^x=\exp x$ is the *definition* of $e^x$. It turns out that $e^x$ has another meaning when $x\in\Bbb Q$. So, Apostol proves that both meanings of $e^x$ lead to the same number when $x$ is rational.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos:   Did you mean Thomas when you typed Apostol?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes. My bad.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos That's true but he didn't do it for IRrational case and just went directly into the definition of $e^{x}$. That's why I put the question.

Answer (score 1):

Having defined $\ln(x)$, $\exp(x)$, and $e$ as you described, there are two ways one might define the function $e^x$:

- Define $e^x = \exp(x)$.
- Define $e^x$ for rational values of $x$ so that it satisfies all the usual laws of exponents, and then extend continuously to the full set of real numbers.

I understand the question to be why these two definitions are equivalent for irrational values of $x$, and the reason is that there is there is only one way to extend the second definition to a *continuous* function, and since $\exp(x)$ agrees with the second definition for rational values and is itself continuous, it must be equal to the unique continuous extension of the second definition to the reals.

Comment: So my understanding here is that: The function R->R: $y = a^{x}$, for ANY positive irrational number $a$, has to be explicitly defined (that is: not only for $e$ but any positive number $a$) because we simply cannot "derive" it from other math equalities. And it also means that we can define it however (= in whatever way) we like so long as the definition makes sense. Is my understand correct?

Comment: Correction to my comment above: $x$ is irrational, $a$ is positive number. Also, it may sound trivial to some of you, but I need to confirm my understanding because I haven't taken any serious course on function or real analysis.

Comment: @TranKhanh Yes, that's it. We can use the desired equality $a^{x+y} = a^x a^y$ to define $a^x$ for any integer value of $x$ (assuming $a^1 = a$), and from there we can use the desired equality $(a^x)^y = a^{xy}$ to extend the definition to rational exponents. But none of the ordinary exponent rules tells us what to do when the exponent is irrational, so the standard choice is to define it so that $a^x$ will be continuous.

Comment: @AnnieCarter I think you *can* in fact work with irrational exponents using the definition given without having to extend it. We only need to realise that an irrational number can be expressed as the sum of an infinite number of rational numbers. So if $w$ is an irrational number, we have \begin{eqnarray}e^w&=&e^{\sum_{k=1}^\infty r_k}\\&=&\prod_{k=1}^\infty e^{r_k}\end{eqnarray} where $r_k$ is a rational number. So we deduce the definition also works for irrational numbers.

Comment: @user7777777 I'm willing to go with that, but in extending the rule $e^{x+y} = e^x e^y$ to $e^{\sum_{k=1}^\infty r_k} = \prod_{k=1}^\infty e^{r_k}$, I think you're implicitly assuming the continuity of $e^x$. There are also convergence issues—you'd need to prove that the limit of the first expression exists if and only if the limit of the second does. I don't think this is a trivial extension of the rule $e^{x + y} = e^x e^y$ in the way that the rule for finite sums/products is.

Answer (score -1):

You can prove first that $\ln(x^p)=p\ln(x)\tag{$\star$}\label{1},$ then $\exp(x)=\exp(x\ln(e))=\exp(\ln(e^x))=e^x$ because $\exp(\cdot)$ is the inverse function of $\ln(\cdot)$ and $\ln(e)=1.$

However, $\eqref{1}$ requires the power rule.

We can start by proving the power rule for non-negative integers, then negative integers, then rational numbers and finally irrational numbers. Doing so, we would have proved the power rule for all real numbers.

For non-negative integer powers, we only need to realise that $(x+h)^n=x^n+nhx^{n-1}+h^2f(x,h)$ where $n$ is a non-negative integer and we don't care what that $f(x,h)$ is for our purposes. You can think about why there's only one $x^n$ by setting $h=0.$ For $hx^{n-1},$ we realise that we are multiplying $n$ $(x+h)$ brackets together so we need to have $n$ variables multiplied together per term, so if we have $n-1$ $x$'s, we should have a single $h.$ As for why we have $n$ of those, it's better to count the number of ways of choosing one $h$ out of the $n$ brackets. It's then easy to see there are $n$ ways for $n$ brackets. Now, we can differentiate using the limit definition.
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{dx^n}{dx}&=&\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(x+h)^n-x^n}{h}\\
&=&\lim_{h\to0}\frac{x^n+nhx^{n-1}+h^2f(x,h)-x^n}{h}\\
&=&\lim_{h\to0}(nx^{n-1}+hf(x,h))\\
&=&nx^{n-1}
\end{eqnarray}
Now for negative powers, we only need to consider the special case $x^{-1}$ and the rest follows by the chain rule.
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{dx^{-1}}{dx}&=&\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\frac1{x+h}-\frac1x}h\\
&=&\lim_{h\to0}\frac{-1}{x(x+h)}\\
&=&-x^{-2}
\end{eqnarray}
Now consider the general case where we take $n$ as a non-negative integer.
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{dx^{-n}}{dx}&=&\frac{d(x^n)^{-1}}{dx}\\
&=&-(x^n)^{-2}(nx^{n-1})\\
&=&-nx^{-n-1}
\end{eqnarray}
So it's the same rule. Now for rational powers, we can agree that for any rational power $r,$ there exist some integers $n,m$ such that
$$(x^r)^m=x^{rm}=x^n$$
We can use the chain rule to find the derivative of the rational power.
\begin{eqnarray}
m(x^r)^{m-1}\frac{dx^r}{dx}&=&nx^{n-1}\\
mx^{rm-r}\frac{dx^r}{dx}&=&rmx^{rm-1}\\
\frac{dx^r}{dx}&=&rx^{r-1}
\end{eqnarray}
Again, the same rule. Now for irrational powers $q,$ we can use the fact that an irrational number can be expressed as the sum of an infinite number of rational numbers $r_k,$ an infinite series; $q=\sum_{k=0}^\infty r_k.$ We can use the product rule to show
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{dx^q}{dx}&=&\frac{dx^{\sum_{k=0}^\infty r_k}}{dx}\\
&=&\frac{d(x^{r_0}\cdot x^{r_1}\cdot x^{r_2}\cdots)}{dx}\\
&=&(x^{r_0}\cdot x^{r_1}\cdot x^{r_2}\cdots)\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{-r_k}\frac{dx^{r_k}}{dx}\\
&=&x^q\sum_{k=0}^\infty r_kx^{-1}\\
&=&qx^{q-1}
\end{eqnarray}
Again, the same rule. So, for all real powers $p,$
$$\frac{dx^p}{dx}=px^{p-1}.$$

Now, we can derive $\ln(x^p)=p\ln(x)$ using the integral definition and the substitution $t=u^p.$
\begin{eqnarray}
\ln(x^p)&=&\int_1^{x^p}\frac{dt}t\\
&=&\int_1^x\frac{pu^{p-1}du}{u^p}\\
&=&p\int_1^x\frac{du}u\\
&=&p\ln(x)
\end{eqnarray}
The final step is showing $\exp(x)=e^x$ as we want which I did in the beginning of the answer.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I don't know, someone did this without comment.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: Isn't the problem about showing that $\exp(x),$ the inverse function of $\ln(x),$ is equal to the function $e^x,$ where $e$ is the number that satisfies $\ln(e)=1,$ for all real $x$?

Comment: Granted, your second line of equalities using the power rule is true by itself, but $e^x$ is defined to be $\exp(x)$. You can't prove definitions.

Comment: I thought $\exp(x)$ was defined to be the inverse of $\ln(x)$ and $e^x$ is just the number $e$ raised to the $x$-th power and that the OP was asking to prove they are the same function.

Comment: A definition is an exact, unambiguous explanation of the meaning of a mathematical word/phrase. You can define the exponential function like that if you want. I also think the OP is asking to prove $\exp(x) = e^x$, or how to "prove" that $\exp(x) = e^x$ holds for irrational $x$, even though they claim by definition the equality holds for all real $x$. Trying to prove $\exp(x)$ and $e^x$ are equal doesn't make sense, just like how trying to prove my name Cody is a name. Someone gave meaning to the string of letters exp just like how someone out there gave meaning to the string of letters Cody.

Comment: I understand what a definition is and that you can choose whatever definition you want and then try to prove things using this definition and valid arguements. The OP's question is confusing. It seems they have two sets of definitions for $\exp(x)$ and $e^x.$

Comment: @Accelerator Quoted from Wikipedia on *Exponentiation*: "So, a definition of the exponential function, denoted $exp(x)$ and of Euler's number are given, which rely only on exponentiation with positive integer exponents.  Then a PROOF is sketched that, if one uses the definition of exponentiation given in preceding sections, one has $exp x = e^{x}$". It did mention a proof of $exp(x) = e^{x}$ exists (but without giving the details)?

Comment: By without giving the details, I mean the page didn't sketch the detailed proof but it already gave a hint for it in the previous section.

Comment: @TranKhanh Ok, so do you think my answer is relevant to your question at all? Cause if not, I can just delete it.

Comment: @user7777777 Your answer is fairly involved for me to assess its validity, and the one presented on Wikipedia is simpler but I'm not 100% sure that sketched proof is sound. If you think it's correct I think you can just leave it there.

Comment: @TranKhanh In that case, if we are going by Wikipedia's way of defining the exponential, then it's safe to say you can prove $\exp(x) = e^x$. But if you define that equality from the get-go like what p. 440 from your textbook quotes, then it wouldn't make sense to prove that definition. That's all.